# Android density same device

Tags: android, device, multiscreen

I develope an App. I position my view calulating the position using the screen size. For example view A, I position axis X 30% screen width and Y 30% screen height.
I test my app in a Samsung S4 (xxhdpi, 1080x1920, 5'').
I test my app in a Sony Xperia Z (xxhdpi, 1080x1920, 5'').

View A in Samsung 4: X= 324 (30% of 1080) Y = 576 (30% of 1920).

View A in Sony Xperia Z: X= 324 (30% of 1080) Y = 576 (30% of 1920)

In the Samsung S4 its OK, but in the sony xperia the view is not ok. Comparing with samsung, its more to the right and are the same device size!

i dont know why this happend and how to fix it.

Greets

Answer (score 1):

I ever have this issue, so i never do the calculation axis X and Y again.

I'm using Margin to all of my android application, and it's going so well so far than you need to use the axis X and Y.

Use the 
 - marginBottom
 - marginTop
 - marginLeft
 - marginRight

Hope it helps!

Comment: dont work because i have to move view with animation so i have to calculate the positions.